# Tray is not built on Electron (Windows)

Tags: electron, tray

We face an Issue with the Creation of a "Tray" (and very often, also JumpLists/UserTaks) on Windows with Electron 6-9 and Windows Version 1809. 
Basically, they are not created at all automatically. The App triggers a Command to build the Tray/Tasks, but this seems to be ignored (or at least, there is no Error shown), the result is even "ok". But - Windows does not show the Tray / the JumpLists/UserTasks.

Nevertheless, if I open Dev Tools and trigger the Command manually, the Tray immediately appears. In 100% of all Cases on all Windows Versions, we could test on. 
We also tried to delay the automatic Creation of the Tray by 5-30 Seconds, but this does not seem to help.

So basically, the main Window triggers an Event, which is sent via ContextBridge (Electron 9) and ipcRenderer.invoke() to ipcMain. This works fine and should not be an Issue - all other Commands work perfectly fine too and the Command is executed.

```
ipcMain.handle('ipc-cmd',async(event,params)=>{... initTray();}
```

The initTray Function:

```
let tray=new Tray(path.join(__dirname,'assets/icon.ico'));
let trayMenu=Menu.buildFromTemplate([...]);
tray.setTooltip(...);
tray.setContextMenu(trayMenu);
tray.on('click',()=>{
    win.isVisible()?win.hide():win.show();
});
```

This should not be any Issue, as its basically standard.
Are there any Circumstances, that can "block" the Creation of the Tray? Is there any Kind of Timing Issue or Reasons, why Windows wont show it? The Creation of the Dock (on MacOS, same Principle) always works fine.

Thanks.